# ffmpeg mp4 to hls vod with extract segment duration without re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello I have h264 mp4 files. What I want to do is convert it to hls without re-encoding. This can be achieve by:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)" -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_type mpegts vid.m3u8
```

But this problem with this is that it doesn't create extract segment duration:

```
$ for f in *.ts; do echo -n "$f,"; ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -sexagesimal -of csv=p=0 "$f"; done
vid0.ts,0:00:04.837700
vid1.ts,0:00:05.587200
vid2.ts,0:00:06.006200
vid3.ts,0:00:01.368200
vid4.ts,0:00:02.693867
```

I don't believe I can't insert keyframes without encoding.

When I run:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)" -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_type mpegts vid.m3u8
```

its works but this is resource intensive as it re-encode the video.

So I am looking for the best way to achieve this while using minimal resource as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only split on keyframes when using `-c copy` (stream copy). So if you need more accurate splitting you need to re-encode.

From the [segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment):

> Note that if you want accurate splitting for a video file, you need to
> make the input key frames correspond to the exact splitting times
> expected by the segmenter, or the segment muxer will start the new
> segment with the key frame found next after the specified start time.

Omit `-c copy` and set keyframe intervals to be equal to your `-hls_time` (or `-segment_time` if using the segment muxer):

```
ffmpeg -i input -f segment -segment_time 4 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)" -reset_timestamps 1 output_%04d.mp4
```

If you prefer to declare the keyframe interval in frames instead of seconds, use `-g` instead of `-force_key_frames` (but don't use both).

Comment: okay thanks, what would be the fastest way to re-encode while using minimal resource as possible ?

Comment: @Jeremy That's a new, different question which would require a new, different answer. Should be posted as a new question.